# How to prevent olive oil container from getting oily outside?

Tags: oil

I'm using this kind of container to add just drops of oil on top of my food or whatever:

[image: Oil bottle]

Problem is it's always oily so after using it I have to clean my hand. Any trick to keep it clean and non oily outside?

Comment: A dropper bottle could work as an alternative container without that disadvantage...

Answer (score 2):

I've worked in a couple kitchens, one of the better methods I saw involved snagging a used pour bottle from the bar, cleaning it out and using that for oil. Something like imaged, with the right-sized bottle.

[image]

Because it has separate tubes for liquid and gas, you usually pour out only what you need. The trick here is that is sounds like you use as little oil as possible, and this method tends to be best for more generous usage.

Comment: I use a similar pourer on my olive oil bottle and it works great. I didn't realize it was because it has an extra tube for air return, but that makes perfect sense!

Comment: but does it keep the bottle clean? I've bought oils which had a smaller pourer already mounted on the bottle below the screw cap. They all have a lip to catch the oil overflow.

Comment: They were all pretty clean, yeah. At least cleaner than those plastic squeeze bottles. But then again, we wiped down the kitchen every night, including the bottles, so we never really let the oil build up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't own such a bottle and thus can't try it myself, but probably the following method works.

1. While standing upright, **squeeze some air out of the bottle**.
2. **Keep it squeezed** while adding the desired amount of oil to your dish.
3. **Loosen your grip** to let the air flow back into the bottle, and **simultaneously tilt it back upright**.

The thought behind this is that the back-flowing air will push the oil back into the bottle and in this way prevent drops.

If you try it, please let me know via comment if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say that I've done this, but what about creating an absorbent ring by rolling a piece of paper towel into several layers and securing it to the top of the bottle with a rubber band?  That way any drips would be soaked up.  Cheap, easy, replaceable.

Comment: Yeah I kinda thought about that, now that you say it I'll give a try tomorrow and report back

Answer (score 0):

Not really except to clean the outside after use. Choice of nozzle can help, but due to the Viscosity coupled with the LACK of skin effect, you'll always get a little bit on the edge even if it's a quarter drop and it will slowly drip down the side.

So...really all you can do is keep it clean.